# Update a nested dict with a Manager from multiprocessor module

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I've been trying to update a nested dictionary using multiprocessing.

I'm able to add the information I want if the dictionary contains a list of elements but if it's a nested dictionary I don't see any changes.

I'm aware that the multiprocessing modules says that it's a dictproxy and not a dict and I've tried changing the example on the module to achieve it but I haven't had any luck.

```
import socket
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from multiprocessing import Pool,Process,current_process,Manager

def dns_lookup(aggregate,ip):
    try:
        hostname=socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
        proc_name = current_process().name
        #print(str(hostname) + " extracted from ip " + str(ip) + " by process id: " + str(proc_name) )
        aggregate[ip]+=hostname
    except Exception as e:
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    procs=[]
    manager=Manager()
    aggregate=manager.dict()
    with open("ip_list.csv","r") as ipfile:
        csv_reader=csv.reader(ipfile)
        for index,row in enumerate(csv_reader):
            if index == 0:
                pass
            else:
                aggregate[row[0]]=row[1:]
                #ips.append((row[0]))
                proc = Process(target=dns_lookup, args=(aggregate,row[0],))
                procs.append(proc)
                proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    pprint(dict(aggregate))
```

The above code works but if I try and change the original dict to

```
aggregate[row[0]]={'Other Items':row[1:]}
```

and then try to update it as

```
d['hostname']=hostname
aggregate[ip]=d
#aggregate[ip]+=d
```

doesn't have any effect.

I need for the actual list to have a dictionary and not a list of elements.

The current file is small but I will have to scale this up to about 10k lookups so multiprocessing is required.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems that the update on the `dict` is not propagated to the other processes. Even migrating the inner dict to `manager.dict()` doesn't solve the problem. What works is if you create a new dict from scratch and apply this to `aggregate[ip]`:

```
aggregate[ip] = {"hostname": hostname, "Other Items": aggregate[ip]['Other Items']}
```

This is maybe a bug, but I would advice you to do bigger changes in your code. There are two shortcomings:

1. You use `aggregate` both as a "queue" of IP's that still need to be looked up and also as a result container, where the processes write to. If you split this up into a queue and a dict that just holds the results makes you avoid the problem you have: Then, you only read from the queue and you only write into the result container `aggregate`.
2. If you have 1'000 lines in your csv file, you'd end up with 1000 processes, whereas your computer can only sever `number-of-cores` processes at a time. On Linux you'd waste a lot of memory that is not needed. On Windows you would start 1'000 python programs from scratch. Use a `Pool` instead and let python figure out the number of cores and distribute your work across these processes.

I have reworked your code into this:

```
import socket
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue, Process, current_process, Manager
from time import sleep

def dns_lookup(aggregate,queue):
    while not queue.empty(): # live as long there are items in the queue
        row = queue.get()
        ip = row[0]
        other_items = row[1:]
        hostname=socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
        aggregate[ip] = {
            "hostname": hostname, 
            "other items": other_items,
            "process_name": current_process().name}

if __name__=='__main__':
    procs=[]
    manager=Manager()
    aggregate=manager.dict()
    queue = Queue()
    with open("ip_list.csv","r") as ipfile:
        csv_reader=csv.reader(ipfile)
        next(csv_reader) # instead of the if index == 0; pass

        for row in csv_reader: # fill queue before starting any processes
            queue.put(row)

        # start x processes, where None says to take x = the number of cpus returned by `cpu_count()`
        pool = Pool(None, dns_lookup, (aggregate, queue))
        pool.close() # signal that we won't submit any more tasks to pool
        pool.join() # wait until all processes are done
        pprint(dict(aggregate))
```

Besides: You would be better of using `Threads` instead of `multiprocessing`, since your processes will be blocked by networking and not CPU. Multiprocessing only makes sense if you can occupy one CPU core to 100%.

Comment: I realized that using process wasn't the best of ways so I switched to a process `Pool` and just used `Proc.apply_async` to get the work done.

I then started looking into threads as you suggested and changed the pool to a ThreadPool from the multiprocessing module. Although more efficient in terms of memory and CPU utilization I do see the threadpool takes longer. It actually takes twice as much time than if I use a process Pool.

Comment: Interesting that the multiprocess approach is faster. If my answer answered all your questions: can you upvote/accept it? Otherwise please ask what's still missing